# How do i create msinfo32.nfo file automatic with a BAT file?

Tags: batch-file

I have a bat file i called it test.bat and inside i added one line:
This is what i tried so far : The problem is that the file never created.

```
start /wait msinfo32.exe /s C:\TEMP\test.nfo
```

When im running the bat file i see the cmd window for second then i see the msinfo32.exe program . But the file test.nfo never created in C:\TEMP

How can i create the test.nfo automatic and how do i make that after the file is created so the msinfo32.exe program will be exit/closed ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I Googled command line options and tested this:

```
start /wait msinfo32.exe /nfo c:\temp\test.nfo
```

See here: http://ss64.com/nt/msinfo32.html